# c# - working with COM+ object in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, com

I am using a third party dll for image processing which returns COM objects. Currently I have declared `DataContract` classes which include some of the information I need from the returned COM objects.

If I want to extend the functionality of my `WCF service`, is there a way to return the COM object directly or will I be required to create new classes and decorate them using `DataContract` manually? (~30 classes)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send a Reference to a COM Object over WCF.

You must serialize it in some way. If the COM Object has a serialize Method you could serialize it to a text, send it over WCF and deserialize it on the other side. But then you need a Reference to the COM object defination on the Client side.

Simplest is to create the New classes, you could try some code generation Tools like resharper to help.